# Remote in Aptana 3 - can not open files - socket error

Tags: sockets

I've installed Eclipse 3.7 and Aptana 3 fresh and set up a remote FTP location. While connecting and browsing the directories everything looks fine but as soon as I want to open a file from the FTP location it stops with the following error:

Opening editor for file...location...has encountered an error. Openin file for read failed.

Opening file for read failed
Software caused connection abort: socket write error

I can access all files at the location with the given login data (it's an admin account).

What's wrong? Any help would be very appreciated.

Thanks in advance.